# Apple Pay & Google Pay (P2P) with Flutter

Tags: flutter, applepay, google-pay

I'm new to Payment Integration and I want to use Apple Pay and Google Pay as an option in my flutter app.

I've discovered this package [Pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) that integerates both of them.

the case is that I want to let my users to be able to send money to each other A.K.A (peer to peer) transactions.

I don't know how exactly to achieve this, send money to another specific user?
and should I handle different merchant ids for different receivers and if so how to do it?

**Note**
[Stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) package is not allowed in the app region.

So, please any help would be appreciated.